# Reload jquery after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax with jquery and after request the jquery stopped and can't edit or delete for example, how can I reload or reactive jquery after ajax request.

This code here:

```
$('.create-div').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url: '.....',
        data: {.....},
    }).done(function(data) {
    // do something
    });

});
```

Can you places help.

Comment: Is your Ajax request working properly?

Comment: This one for create new data, working but the others stopped , I have one for delete and one for edit.

Comment: Can you post your edit and delete code too

Comment: Something in the `.done` function is doing this, so we need to see that code.